# Remove a section number

Tags: sectioning

I'm sure this is a basic question asked before but my search of the site did not yield a result (likely b/c I don't know what I'm searching for).

I want to print out a reference section that is included in the bookmarks but the header gets centered and it has no number next to it.

Here is a minimal sample and a bib file (PS not sure how to include the bib file in code as I call a separate outside file).  I also included all calls to packages because I find this information is sometimes needed by people helping.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{proj.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1}}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\defbibheading{bibliography}{%
\section{\normalfont\refname}}

\begin{document}

\section{guy}
a
\section{gal}
b \cite{test}
\printbibliography
%\appendix
%\section{}

\end{document}
```

bib file:

```
@Booklet{test,
  author       = {Joseph (Yossi) Gil},
  TITLE        = {{\LaTeXe} for Graduate Students},
  year         = {2002},
  howpublished = {manuscript},
  address      = {Haifa, Israel},
}
```

Currently the pdf output looks like this:

```
1 guy

a 

2 gal

b Gil, 2002

3 References
Gil, J. ( (2002). LATEX 2ε for graduate students. manuscript.
```

I'm hoping to make it:

```
1 guy

a 

2 gal

b Gil, 2002

                          References
Gil, J. ( (2002). LATEX 2ε for graduate students. manuscript.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1}}

\defbibheading{center}{%
  \phantomsection
  \section*{\centering\normalfont\refname}
  \pdfbookmark{\refname}{References}
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\section{guy}
a
\section{gal}
b 
\printbibliography[heading=center]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is to use `\pdfbookmark` (from `hyperref`) inside `\defbibheading` to add the bookmark.

Comment: Thank you both for the correct response/explanation and showing me how to include a bib in the example.  I'm bookmarking this one for future reference in providing a reproducible example. +1